# How to find Part of a String and echo it out?

Tags: php

`$string = "David Smith (Local/202@from-queue/n from SIP/202) (ringinuse enabled) (Not in      use) has taken 1 calls (last was 843 secs ago)";`

I need to echo out the calls taken `(1)`.

I have tried:

```
$taken_calls = substr($string, 'taken ', 4 );
```

How do I do that? Thankyou.

Comment: Read the chapter on regular expressions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$string = "David Smith (Local/202@from-queue/n from SIP/202) (ringinuse enabled) (Not in use) has taken 1 calls (last was 843 secs ago)";
$result= array();
preg_match("/taken\s(\d+)/", $string, $result);

var_dump($result);
```

Result:

```
array(2) { 
           [0]=> string(7) "taken 1" 
           [1]=> string(1) "1"    // this is your number 
}
```

Edit: Now, the number could have more than 1 digit

Comment: whats the preg_match if the number is more than one, sometimes the number could be 2 digits or 3 digits long. At the moment if the number is 12 I only get 1 in the array string.

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expressions:

```
<?php
$string = "David Smith (Local/202@from-queue/n from SIP/202) (ringinuse enabled) (Not in use) has taken 1 calls (last was 843 secs ago)";
$matches = array();

if (1 === preg_match('/taken (\d+) calls/', $string, $matches)) {
    echo $matches[1];
}
```